# million of map outputs for one map input. is it efficient?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

so, what I do is, I map a text file as a whole record (wholefileinputformat), do some processing, then write the output line by line with context.write. The problem is, it turns out to be not efficient at all. One map task produces several millions of outputs and I get Heap Memory error. Is there any other way of doing this?

```
   map-input(file_name, file_contents_as_Text)  
   String output = process(file_contents)   
   for(each line in output)   
        context.write(line, some_value)
```

Comment: What type of processing are you doing on that file before emitting all of the records? The solution will depend on how you could change that algorithm to avoid loading entire files into memory.

Comment: the file needs to be processed as a whole. I can not partition it because the result depends on the whole file. the only work around I can think of is to somehow trying to find something in common in those unique output values so that I can send out them as fewer combined values

Comment: by the way, the files are actually relatively small - just a few thousands of lines. But the number of outputs produced by processing these files could be exponentially high

Comment: You can try setting the JVM heap size bigger using `mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1G` or something like that. Or, like you said, find a way to emit less data. You could look into using a Combiner, if possible.

Comment: I already tried to increase the mapred.child.java.opts but it seems it is not the solution. 
`map-input(file_name, file_contents_as_Text)`  

`String output = process(file_contents)`  

`for(each line in output)`  

`context.write(line, some_value)`